# How to bind DataGrid Sorting event to Prism ViewModel DelegateCommand

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid, prism

How do I bind the sorting command of my datagrid to view model?

Below is my XAML Code

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ViewModels}"
          CanUserSortColumns="True"
          Sorting="{Binding ViewModel_SortingCommand}">
</DataGrid>
```

Below is the ViewModel implemented that cause the error in binding

```
ViewModel_SortingCommand = new DelegateCommand<DataGridSortingEventArgs>(ViewModel_Sorting;

public void ViewModel_Sorting(DataGridSortingEventArgs args)
{
    // Error on binding
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since [`Sorting`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagrid.sorting?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid.Sorting);k(VS.XamlEditor)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netcore-3.1) is an event, you cannot bind it directly, but you can use an `EventTrigger`.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ViewModels}"
          CanUserSortColumns="True">
   <i:Interaction.Triggers>
      <i:EventTrigger EventName="Sorting">
         <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ViewModel_SortingCommand}"/>
      </i:EventTrigger>
   </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</DataGrid>
```

If you use the legacy blend behaviors shipped with Blend, use this namespace:

```
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
```

If you use the new *[Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf/)* Nuget package, use this namespace:

```
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors"
```

If you need to process the event args in your command, set `PassEventArgsToCommand` to `True`:

```
<b:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding FavContextMenuEditCmd}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True"/>
```

Also note, that there is an `EventArgsParameterPath` property to specify a property in the event args that should be passed to the command and an `EventArgsConverter` property to use a converter. These are useful to avoid passing UI related types like event args to your view model.

Answer (score 1):

Passing a `DataGridSortingEventArgs` to a view model breaks the MVVM pattern.

You should either perform the sorting in the view/control or, if you are really interested in the sort order in the context of the view model, sort the actual source collection that the view binds to. In general, the view model isn't interested in or aware of how the user sorts, groups or filter the data in the view.

Either way, the view model should not depend on a `DataGridSortingEventArgs` or anything else that is related to the `DataGrid` control in the view.